# Correct way caching data on iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, caching

What is the correct way to cache file and/or string data on ios?
Is CoreData useful for this, or is there a better wat of doing this?

What is the best method to cache for performance and what for caching for persistence for any amount of data?

I can't seem to find any nice Apple docs about this subject.

Comment: What kind of caching do you want? In memory or on disk caching? And what is your deployment target?

Comment: and what kind of data are you caching? Images? App state? Text?

Comment: @kubi Images are not needed to be cached explicitly, everything else is no different.

Comment: How much data are you caching? Are you caching for performance reasons or persistence reasons?

Comment: @bioffe Not true. It's important to know the volume of data before being able to recommend a caching strategy. A couple of lines of text is very different to a hundred image files.

Comment: I am caching the contents of a file, or a string.

Comment: @Stephen Once again you don't need to cache hundred image files. UIKit does it for you unless you really want to reinvent the wheel.  I implemented my own image caching facilities(btw using `NSCache`) which benchmarks slightly better than `+imageNamed:`. I have unique situation when I have hundreds of *tiny* images. To the wast majority developers it would be overkill and waste of time.  As to entity persistance, it's a completely different subject.

Comment: @Stephen Aside from the above. One would need some sort of a mapping data-structure(let's not discuss array+index approach here). Would you agree? If you have a better solution, please share.

Comment: @bioffe If we assume that caching means "in memory" then I agree with you. But it's not the only use of the word cache. I could say that I _cache_ the results from a web service, and the results are persisted between launches. That would imply a different structure than, say, a text file. Especially if there's more data than there is memory.

Comment: btw `NSCache` does a good job of handling `NSDiscardableContent` protocol objects, if there is a situation of "More data than memory".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer `NSCache` docs here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: +1 for a surprising answer. I had no idea NSCache was available in iOS.

Comment: @mrthys  Note that `NSCache` is is a very simple in-memory cache. It does not handle only caching for a specific amount of time or clearing the cache if there is in-app memory warnings. In addition, since it's an in-memory cache, the cache disappear when the app is closed _or_ backgrounded.

`NSCache` can definitely be a useful tool, but really all it is is an `NSDictionary` that can remove cached items if memory pressure from other applications is detected.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different solutions to this problem and there is no "right" way to do it. A few popular options are:

Core Data - Apple's framework for persistence. Very performant, but more difficult.
SQLite - Fast and flexible, but bare bones.
Plists - Basically writing a file to disk, you have to read and write manually.
NSUserDefaults - The lightest weight "key-value" option.
I would encourage you to read up on all four and see which one works best for you.